# PHP Mail function and Sendmail

Tags: 11.04, php, mail

I'm trying to get the PHP mail() function to work. But it fails to send emails.  I run Ubuntu 11.04. I installed sendmail.

I opened the php.ini and set

```
; For Unix only. You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
sendmail_from = no-reply@mydomain.com
```

Then I restarted apache.

Then created a simple PHP script to test it but no luck.

When I try to run sendmail it gives me a permissions error, so I have to run 'sudo sendmail'.  Does my mail system failure have anything to do with permissions? Is there further configuration I need to do with sendmail?

Thanks.

EDIT: The error is this:

```
user@server:~$ sendmail
Command 'sendmail' is available in '/usr/sbin/sendmail'
The command could not be located because '/usr/sbin/' is not included in the PATH
environment variable. This is most likely caused by the lack of administrative
privileges associated with your user account.
sendmail: command not found
user@server:~$ sudo sendmail
sendmail: No recipients supplied - mail will not be sent
```

Comment: Depends on the permission problems. Which errors do you get?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer - if your needs are limited, use ssmtp and also in that case postfix is a huge overkill. But if you wish to learn about mailservers, go on. I have not been so brave, yet :)

Comment: @Jesse Please post your solution as an answer - this isn't a forum, don't edit your question with the solution.

Comment: No problem. I have to wait 13 hours now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this

sudo apt-get install postfix

And now everything is running perfectly. Sendmail apparently isn't the answer. Postfix is.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your user to mail group like this:

```
sudo adduser yourusername mail
```

And if you are using PHP with HTTP server (such as Apache), you'll need to do this to:

```
sudo adduser www-data mail
```

Apart from the actual question - if your mailing needs are limited to personal/local development  - I highly recommend ssmtp.

Comment: So 'www-data' is the apache web user? That's good to know.

Comment: Yes it is on Ubuntu. In other distributions it can be different. For example in Fedora 14 it's  user _apache_.

Comment: Are you certain www-data is the user for Apache2 by default?  I just installed Apache2 and it runs as root (which is irrelevant because the webserver isnt internet facing), but I don't think www-data is the user group by default that Apache runs as.

Comment: I am pretty sure. For example you need the served files to be owned by www-data group. If they are owned by root, you get 403 in browser. Also, files created by PHP/Apache belong to www-data. At least on my Ubuntu 11.04 :)